# What can we say about a function on a manifold whose differential is zero?

Tags: manifolds, differential-forms

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold and $f\colon M\to\mathbf{R}$ a differentiable function. If $\mathrm{d}f=0$, what can we say about $f$? Is it constant?

**Motivation:**

In Thermodynamics, we consider some "state space" $M$ and "state variables"
$\newcommand{\dif}{\mathrm{d}}$
\begin{align}
X_1,\ldots,X_n,\xi_1,\ldots,\xi_n\colon M&\to\mathbf{R}
\end{align}
such that the function
$(X_1,\ldots,X_n)\colon M\to\mathbf{R}^n$ is a chart (in particular, injective).

The energy $E\colon M\to\mathbf{R}$ is then said to satisfy
$$\dif E=\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i\cdot\dif X_i$$
and I was wondering if $E$ is determined up to some constant by this.

Answer (score 1):

I expect it's piecewise constant.  If the manifold is a pair of spheres, $f$ might take one value on one sphere and a different value on the other.

Comment: I understand. Do you think that $f$ can be shown to be constant under some additional assumptions regarding the topology, e.g. connectedness?

Comment: Well, I guess that's exactly what your are implying with your answer :)

Comment: To be honest, I don't have a grasp on the math details.  If you pull back to $\mathbb R^n$ then df is still 0 so f is constant on each patch.  I guess connectedness makes f constant

Comment: Allright, thanks for the reply. Btw, I added some motivation to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, let's consider a trivial manifold, i.e. a manifold covered by one single chart $X\colon M\to D\subset \mathbf{R}^n$. Then $f$ is obviously constant if and only if
$$F:=f\circ X^{-1}\colon D\to\mathbf{R}$$
is constant. And if $D$ is connected, then the total derivative of $F$ is zero if and only if $F$ is constant.

The more general case can be solved by using the fact that each point has a neighbourhood which is a trivial manifold.